# How do you texture with a photo taken from an angle without distorting it based on the polygons?

Tags: texturing, uv

Recently I ahve been trying to take a more "quick and dirty" aproach to 3d design, and one of the problems that I have encountered is that making uv projections without much thought (aproximating the position of vertices a lot) in an image taken from an angle produces distortions because it is calculated in a per-polygon basis, which forces me to make a lot of subdivisions (which I have seen done in the tutorials I have watched, but it makes it hard to modify geometry later). Using the subdivision surfave modifier and extra vertices in edges (to keep them sharp) doesn't work (or I'm doing it wrong), as it makes the corners stretch. How should I aproach this?

Quick example of what happens:

How it looks:
[image: how it looks]

With subdivisions:
[image: How it should look]

With subdivision surface:
[image: With subdivision surface modifier]

Comment: try marking the sharp edges as creases (shift+E) instead of adding vertices?

Answer (score 3):

I am maybe misunderstanding what you are trying to do but will ask anyways.If all you are trying to do is map the 2D image to the 3D box shape why are you using any subdivisions at all ?

Surely the simplest approach is to select the 3 appropriate faces of the simple cuboid and <kbd>U</kbd> to open the **UV Mapping** menu and choose the **Unwrap** option, then reposition the 7 vertices in the UV space as accurately as you can over the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I think that you could just try just setting the subdivide type from "catmull-clark" to "simple". Hope this helps!